# Convert list of strings to list of numbers (both float and integers)

Tags: list, types, prolog

I have following data in text file I read from stdin:

```
4.5 12 -16
12 37 -43
-1.6 -4.3 98

1
2
3.3
```

I execute some basic parsing on it and get to a (wanted) point where I have it parsed to structure as follows:

```
[[[4,.,5],[1,2],[-,1,6]],[[1,2],[3,7],[-,4,3]],[[-,1,.,6],[-,4,.,3],[9,8]],[[]],[[1]],[[2]],[[3,.,3],[]]]
```

Which basically is a list of lines, where lines are also lists of numbers represented as list of chars. Now I would like to convert it to list of lines, where line would be a list of numbers - mixed list of both float and integer values. So my questions: Is mixed list even possible in Prolog? And how would I convert string to either integer or float  based on presence of 'dot'?

I tried using plain `atom_string(X, [1,.,5]).`to test whether this is the way, but it ends up with Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated (which I somehow don't understand, when both of the arguments should be of '?' type which would mean that they can be both input and output variables.

Comment: use `number_chars(X, ['1',.,'5']).` instead! Note that you have to write `'1'` for the character 1, not `1` alone.

Comment: More compactly, you can write `"1.5"` for `['1',.,'5']` when you `set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).`

Comment: `maplist(number_chars,Numbers,Strings)`

Comment: @false There is a slight problem though. I have the structure as described and I do not know how to convert `[4,.,5]` and similar to `['4', ., '5']`. Now I think I was able to create a function to convert one of these elements: `convToNmb(A,Z) :- atomic_list_concat(A,X),atom_chars(X,Y),number_chars(Z,Y).` How will I now be able to apply that on every of 2nd level lists to get list of list of numbers?

Comment: Where do you get `[4,.,5]` from?

Comment: Your workaround is a pretty unreliable hack.

Comment: @false I am trying to complete some code provided by our exercise lector that reads from stdin and saves the data in described format. It _should_ be characters, but since the output is missing apostrophes, it is is probably somehow converted to... codes, maybe? I also assume that those are as described because this is what I get when I call write(S), where S is a variable containing the structure I am trying to work with. How would you improve that hack? What are the dangers?

Comment: @boris Commas are separators of elements within the list, dot should be decimal separator for the resulting number, e.g. for [4,.,5] I want to get float value 4.5, similarly for [4,3,5] I expect integer value of 435.

Comment: @boris I see, that was my mistake. Only dots should be used as separators, commas were typo. I edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot guess which Prolog you are using, but in case you are using SWI-Prolog, there is a nice little library, [`library(dcg/basics)`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/dcg/basics.pl?show=src). It is a bit difficult to find, but it has DCG primitives for parsing that make this a very easy task. If you are not using SWI-Prolog you could just copy the library, or use the definitions that it has in your code (make sure to read the license!).

So here is the solution in SWI-Prolog:

```
:- use_module(library(dcg/basics)).

input_to_numbers(Input, Numbers) :-
    phrase_from_stream(numbers(Numbers), Input).

numbers([]) --> eos, !.
numbers([Ns|Rest]) -->
    nums_line(Ns), !,
    numbers(Rest).

nums_line([N|Ns]) -->
    whites,
    number(N), !,
    nums_line(Ns).
nums_line([]) --> blanks_to_nl.
```

It uses the following DCGs from the library: `eos//0`, `whites//0`, `number//1`, and `blanks_to_nl//0`. Note that `number//1` can read either an integer or a float, and also reads floats written as `1.7e3` for example.

This particular implementation insists to read every line, and for lines without numbers it will give you an empty list. It can only return an empty list if the input is completely empty! It will fail if there is any non-number in your input. But once you have the primitives it is easy to adjust to your needs.

This is the complete code, you just need to feed your example file somehow to it. If you want to do it from "standard input", you would use `user_input` as the input stream:

```
?- input_to_numbers(user_input, Ns).
|: 4.5 12 -16
|: 12 37 -43
|: -1.6 -4.3 98
|: 
|: 1
|: 2
|: 3.3
Ns = [[4.5, 12, -16], [12, 37, -43], [-1.6, -4.3, 98], [], [1], [2], [3.3]].
```

So I called this from the top level and just pasted the contents and typed Ctrl-D to put end-of-file. If you had your input in a file, you could instead do:

```
?- setup_call_cleanup(open('nums.txt', read, In),
        input_to_numbers(In, Ns),
        close(In)).
In = <stream>(0x19a6740),
Ns = [[4.5, 12, -16], [12, 37, -43], [-1.6, -4.3, 98], [], [1], [2], [3.3]].
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you still need to parse numbers using comma as decimal separator, here is a simple way (replace number//1 with number_//1 in the DCG Boris has posted):

```
number_(Number) -->
    (   integer(Int), ",", integer(Frac)
    ->  {format(codes(Cs), '~d.~d', [Int, Frac]), number_codes(Number, Cs)}
    ;   number(Number)
    ).
```

It shows how flexible the DCG notation can be...

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just redefine `dot//0` to be `dot --> ",".`?

Comment: I didn't know about this possibility, anyway the (original) sample data had mixed case (both comma and dot separated numbers)

Comment: I was left with the impression that it was a mistake to have a mix of both in the question, it was edited by OP itself after I asked about it.

Comment: I wonder how dot//0 could be redefined, since it's internal to the library . Did you tried it, with redefine_system_predicate  ?

Comment: No, I didn't try. First option would have been to just edit the library.... I was actually now looking into how it can be done. I don't see a reason why `retractall` followed by `assertz` shouldn't work, but I haven't had the chance to try it just yet.

Comment: The "easy" seems to be to just rewrite the source of `basics.pl`. I cannot find any reasonable way to redefine a non-exported predicate. If I can't figure it out I might even ask a question myself.